# How to do Custom join with Child Entity for a field in JPA?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

Hi i have below two entity tables where LOANS is my parent class and DDL Table class is child . The join is custom join . I have other child tables which am able to join correctly. But for this DDL table i want to try a custom join . I am not sure how i can achieve it . The Oracle Query i am trying to achieve is below . How i can do this . Open for Suggestions if this not the correct way of doing it .

Oracle Query

```
select dt.DESCRIPTION 
from LOANS l,ddl_table dt
where
        dt.table_name='master' and dt.field_name='mc'
        and  SUBSTR(dt.DESCRIPTION, 2, 1) = l.MC_TYPE
        and l.LOAN_ID = :LOAN_ID
```

Parent Entity

```
@DynamicUpdate
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Table(name = "LOANS")
@Entity
public class Loans {

@Id
@Column(name = "LOAN_ID")
private Long loanId;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@WhereJoinTable(clause = "table_name='master' and field_name='type'")
private DDLTable  ddlTable;
// Other child tables.
}
```

DDL Table Entity

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Table(name = "DDL_TABLE")
@Entity
public class DDLTable {

@Id
@Column(name = "TABLE_NAME")
private String tableName;
@Id
@Column(name = "FIELD_NAME")
private String fieldName;

@Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
private String description;

@Column(name = "FILTER_TYPE")
private String filterType;

}
```

Comment: `@WhereJoinTable` applies to intermediary join tables only. It seems you don't have one. You might want to take a look at `@JoinFormula` instead

Comment: Ok looking to that , But will it accept the dynamic parameter . In my case along with static parameters i need the LOAN_ID from the parent table .

Comment: Do you want to (1) establish an association between `Loans` and `DdlTable`, or (2) simply execute the query you posted? If the former, then only the `dt.table_name='master' and dt.field_name='mc' and  SUBSTR(dt.DESCRIPTION, 2, 1) = l.MC_TYPE` part becomes the join clause. You will then be able to call `em.find(Loans.class, loanId)` and the `Loans.ddlTable` will be populated in the result. If the latter, there's no need for the `Loans.ddlTable` field at all, your query can be translated easily into JPQL.

Comment: Second option of simply executing the query also will work for me , but i need the result inside Loans Entity . I am not sure how i can bring that result inside Loans Entity

Comment: Can u add this as answer , I will accept it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to (1) establish an association between `Loans` and `DdlTable`, or (2) simply execute the query you posted?

If the former, then only the `dt.table_name='master' and dt.field_name='mc' and  SUBSTR(dt.DESCRIPTION, 2, 1) = l.MC_TYPE` part becomes the join clause. You will then be able to call `em.find(Loans.class, loanId)` and the `Loans.ddlTable` will be populated in the result. You'll want sth along the lines of:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinFormula(formula = "SELECT SUBSTR(dt.DESCRIPTION, 2, 1) FROM ddl_table dt WHERE dt.table_name='master' and dt.field_name='mc'", referencedColumnName = "MC_TYPE")
```

If the latter, there's no need for the `Loans.ddlTable` field at all, your query can be translated easily into JPQL:

```
SELECT dt.description
from Loans l, DdlTable dt
where
        dt.tableName='master' and dt.fieldName='mc'
        and  SUBSTRING(dt.description, 2, 1) = l.mcType
        and l.loanId = :LOAN_ID
```

As a side note, I'd think about mapping `SUBSTRING(dt.description, 2, 1)` as a virtual column in your DB to make the entity mapping easier. Perhaps even a dedicated view with `dt.tableName='master' and dt.fieldName='mc'`. You could index `SUBSTRING(dt.description, 2, 1)` for faster lookup.